# How to store string integer pair other than hash map?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

This is my recycler view in which I am storing my expense related information . I want to sum the amount paid of each corresponding user . For example , **sadaf : Rs (50+10+5)=65 , Gulatiji: (50)Rs =50 , Amen :(50+5)= Rs 55** .

I thought of using hash map but the problem is that the user names in my recycler view are not unique . So , how should I store the sum of each corresponding user . 
I have also tried this but this is giving me the wrong answer . 
I am able to successfully sum the **total amount column** but for the **amount paid** , it is giving me the wrong answer. For the time being , I was just trying to calculate the total amount of a single user by using an integer variable my_total .**I am getting the answer for sadaf as 110 but it should be 65.**

```
 calcuationAdap = new CalcuationAdap(Calculation.this,data);
                    for (int i = 0 ;i<data.size();i++) {
                        System.out.println(data.get(i).getItem());
                        main_total = main_total + Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getTot_amt());
                    }

                    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
                    {
                        for( int j=i+1;j<data.size()-1;j++)
                        {
                            if(data.get(i).getUser_name().equals(data.get(j).getUser_name()))
                            {
                                System.out.println(data.get(i).getUser_name());
                                my_total = my_total+Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getMy_amt());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(main_total ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(my_total), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I guess u can have a pojo/model class for String Name,int amount and try using  that i.e.,ArrayList<UserExpense> userExpensesList;

Comment: can u please make it more clear.. :)

Comment: "user names in my recycler view are not unique" what it means? is it username may contain lower and uppercase letter?

Comment: it means that in my recycler view , two people can have same name and in hash map , we have unique keys , so I can't use user name as key if i use hash map .

Comment: is there any userId for a particular user?

Comment: yes ,  but I haven't parsed it . Is it possible to do it without userid

Comment: No . you can't. You have to identify a user. username is not unique. parse userid. then use the userId to identify a user

Comment: ok we will try it ....and let u know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171775/discussion-between-user6914996-and-vinayak-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have user id then use user id. other wise use below code to get each total amount

```
 calcuationAdap = new CalcuationAdap(Calculation.this,data);

    HashMap<String,Integer> result =new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0 ;i<data.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(data.get(i).getItem());
        main_total = main_total + Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getTot_amt());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++) {
        if (result.containsKey(data.get(i).getUser_name())){
            Integer addTotal=result.get(data.get(i).getUser_name());
            addTotal= addTotal + Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getMy_amt());
            result.put(data.get(i).getUser_name(),addTotal);
        }else {
            result.put(data.get(i).getUser_name(),Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getMy_amt()));
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(main_total ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:result.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a model class like

```
public class MyDataClass {
    String userName;
    String date;
    String item;
    int totoalAmount;
    int amountPaid;

    public int getAmountPaid() {
        return amountPaid;
    }

    public int getTotoalAmount() {
        return totoalAmount;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setAmountPaid(int amountPaid) {
        this.amountPaid = amountPaid;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void setTotoalAmount(int totoalAmount) {
        this.totoalAmount = totoalAmount;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

and whenever you need to store data as a list of such type create array list of this type like 
ArrayList list =new ArrayList<>()
and create object of this class to store data with getter methods like

```
MyDataClass data =new MyDataClass()
data.setUserName("userName")
....
list.add(data);
```

and whenever you need to get data use getter method to get data like

```
list.get(index).getUserName();
```

Comment: okay but how we will keep track of every expense for a particular user .I mean that we will be able to add the user name for example sadaf in the array list but how will i be able to add her total expense i.e Rs 65

Comment: you can update list if you have calculated total amount

Comment: just search for the user in list and on that index you can assign total amount

Comment: yes , but I want to keep store the list like this  Sadaf : Rs 65 Gulatiji :Rs 50 , Amen : Rs 55

Comment: Okay got it Thanks :)

Comment: setters and getters are an unnecessary step, you can just make those fields public and access them directly. Unless you need to make more than an operation in those methods, the direct approach is better.

Comment: making member public and accessing it outside is not a good practice